# How to plot this dataset? (error: no numeric data to plot)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]
So this is how my dataset looks like but when i use

```
plot.line()
```

it gives me the error " no numeric data to plot"

apply to numeric doesn't seem to work

Comment: `df.plot('Country Name' , 'China')`

Answer (score 1):

check if the below code helps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df.iloc[:,0]
y = df.iloc[:,1]
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it gives errors. it doesn't understand area/colors/alpha and if i delete those parts and only put it in (x, y) it gives me this  : https://ibb.co/xY6P4jf

Comment: Okay, i think you can get rid of area/colors/alpha. i am sure your data is very big data that i why the plot is not very precise. You can still see how it works by working with the subset of the data by doing `df = df.head(50)` now look how your plot is.

Comment: alternate way: also you can how your plot looks like by doing `df.plot("Country Name", "China")`

Comment: okay so it seems i used your code on the original data and that's why it looked like that. but when i use it on the dataset that i posted above it gives me "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = df.head(50)
x = df.iloc[:,0]
y = df.iloc[:,1]
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()`
can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

There are so, so many ways!

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(x="Country Name", y="China", data=df)

sns.lineplot(x="Country Name", y="China", data=df)

sns.barplot(x="Country Name", y="China", data=df)
```

See the links below for more info.

https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/introduction